# Extract features from hidden layer mlp using sklearn.neural_network

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I want to extract hidden layer's features of MLP using sklearn.neural_network. Can someone share his/her thoughts?

Comment: What features you're looking for ? weights and intercept ?

Comment: No, I want to extract the activation given a pattern in input from the last layer of a MLP.